# How to Make HTML Elements Cluster Together Using Pure JavaScript or CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, data-visualization

Alternate Title: How to Make Bubble Chart in Pure HTML and JavaScript / Without SVG

I am working on a project where I am trying to show the visualization of a dataset as a cluster of arbitrarily-sized circles. I would use a library like d3.js but these elements each need to be heavily styled (3d animations on hover, etc.) and must have child elements in a way that SVG does does not support. Currently, I am using the following CSS flow style for the elements.

```
position: relative;
float: left;
margin: 1rem;
```

The following is the result.

[image: Current Visualization]

What I am trying to achieve a similar effect to is the following.

[image: Target Visualization]

I am good with any solution involving any amount of JavaScript, CSS, and/or HTML with any additional library, just as long as I can use the solution with an arbitrarily-styled and arbitrarily-animated circular HTML element.

Comment: use `position:absolute`, manipulate the style `left` and `top` of the element, keep in mind that it is relative to the top-left of the node not the center, then you can use d3-force to position the elements. Adding a linear/radial-gradient to a SVG circle is no problem

Comment: It is more than a linear gradient, I'm afraid. I just didn't want to spam the question with unrelated CSS styles. Each of the elements are made to perform a 3d transform on hover, that gives off a "flipping" effect to reveal information on the other side. As far as I know, there is no trivial-to-implement analog in SVG, but correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: like you position the elements absolute in the SVG you can position them absolute on the page

Comment: Check these out :https://beta.observablehq.com/@mbostock/d3-bubble-chart

Comment: https://beta.observablehq.com/@mbostock/exoplanets

Comment: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1893974